# Way to know the type of ads being served from Google ad manager while using Google Publisher Tag

Tags: javascript, banner-ads, native-ads, google-publisher-tag

Is there a way to know the type of ad(Native/Banner ad) being served in each ad slot from Google ad manager on a website?
I am using a code snippet similar to what is provided in the gpt documentation:

```
<script>
      window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
      googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag
            .defineSlot(
                '/6355419/Travel/Europe/France/Paris', [300, 250], 'div-id')
            .addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.enableServices();
      });
    </script>

<div id="div-id" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;">
      <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
          googletag.display('div-id');
        });
      </script>
    </div>
```

Is there any event that I can listen to, in order to know the ad type?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Publisher Tag API enables you to retrieve the `creativeTemplateId` used for each rendered slot.

As long as you know your templates ids, you should be able to do specific actions :

```
<script>
window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  googletag
    .defineSlot('/6355419/Travel/Europe/France/Paris', [300, 250], 'div-id')
    .addService(googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded',function(event) {
       var slot = event.slot;
       console.group('Slot', slot.getSlotElementId(), 'finished rendering.')
       // Log details of the rendered ad.
       console.log('Creative Template ID:', event.creativeTemplateId);
       console.groupEnd();
       if(event.creativeTemplateId === yourIdentifiedTemplateId) {
         //your specific action
       }
      }));
  );
googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>

<div id="div-id" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;">
<script>
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.display('div-id');
  });
</script>
</div>
```

Concerning `yourIdentifiedTemplateId` :

- it is an integer (not a string)
- you will find it in your Google Ad Manager UI (in "Native ad formats" page for native, in your creative template URL for custom display templates)

Full documentation :

- GPT slotRendedEnded event  [[here]](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.events.slotrenderendedevent)
- GPT ResponseInformation  [[here]](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.ResponseInformation_creativeTemplateId)

Hope this helps ;)